# String Literal Pool

Tags: c

Что такое `String Literal Pool`? Когда он используется?

Comment: Ваш вопрос точно про язык C?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, точно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не уверен, что мы говорим об одном, но попробую ответить. Строка в C - это массив символов, как известно. Память под этот массив может быть выделена в кадре стека

```
char str[4];
str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'c';
str[3] = '\0';
```

в куче

```
char *str = malloc(4);
str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'c';
str[3] = '\0';
```

но намного чаще строки можно увидеть в виде строковых литералов

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

или

```
char *str = "abc";
```

При таком объявлении строки, компилятор сам выделяет память в специальной области<sup>1</sup>, доступной только для чтения. Именно в неё указывает указатель `*str` из последнего примера. Если честно, я первый раз слышу, чтобы её называли String Literal Pool, но скорее всего это как раз про неё.

---

1. Точнее создаёт секцию объектного файла, которая потом загружается в эту область при запуске исполняемого файла.